# Training Pocketsphinx on raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, speech-recognition

how do i train pocketsphinx to accurately recognize spoken letters and numbers with near 100% accuracy? What model should i adapt to recognize similar sounding letters like 'b' and 'd'?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard, unless you have a lot of data.

You'd better use radio alphabet "alpha", "bravo", "charlie".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, we cant use radio alphabet in our project. would it be possible if we train the default acoustic model of pocketsphinx with a lot of data? we only need to recognize atleast 2 speakers in our project. thanks!

Comment: Ok, sure, training tutorial is here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam. Data requirements are also listed there, you need 5 hours of recordings at least.

Answer (score 0):

Shrink your language model to just include those keywords you want. The hugely increases accuracy